# Multiplication through repeated addition

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to multiply two arrays of digits through repeated addition. So the number 324 = [4,2,3] times 24 = [4,2]. What im getting stuck on is iterating the addition of 324 and 324, Saving that into an array as [8,4,6] then reiterating the addition process to get [8,4,6]+[4,2,3] etc etc. This is what I have so far:

```
BigInt result = new BigInt();
BigInt temp = new BigInt();
int sum = 0;
int carry = 0;
int size = digitList.size();
int k = 0; //k is our multiplier 
for (int i = otherBigInt.digitList.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
    k = 10 * k + otherBigInt.digitList.get(i);
}
```

This is where I perform the long addition, digit by digit.

```
for (int i =0; i<size;i++) {
    sum = digitList.get(i) + digitList.get(i) + carry;
    if (sum > 9) {
        temp.digitList.add(sum%10);
        carry=1;
    } else {
        temp.digitList.add(sum);
        carry=0;
    }
    if (sum > 9 && i == size-1) {
        temp.digitList.add(sum/10);
    }
}
```

This is where I get stuck. What I'm trying to do here is to add 324 to the temporary array whereby it's answer then gets assigned to the result array. From here I assign the result to the temp array so that I can add to the stored result. eg: digitlist = 324, temp = 324. Result = 648 --> digitList=324, temp = 648.  result = 972.

I clear the result array, so I can store a more recent result each iteration. At this point I get a nullpointerExeption where index = 0 and size =0.

```
for(int i=0;i<25;i++) {
    result.digitList.clear();
    for (int j=0; j<digitList.size();j++) {
        sum = digitList.get(j) + temp.digitList.get(j) + carry;
        if (sum > 9) {
            result.digitList.add(sum%10);
            carry=1;
        } else {
            result.digitList.add(sum);
            carry=0;
        }
        if (sum > 9 && j == size-1) {
            result.digitList.add(sum/10);
        }
    }
    temp.digitList = result.digitList;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is a homework question, however I've been stuck on it for a while. The solution I'm coming to seems too complex for such a simple task, could someone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the assignment? Traditionally, multiplication of x*y through repeated addition is done by adding x to the result for y number of times: `int result = 0; while (y > 0) { result += x; y--; }`

Comment: @Robby Cornelissen I was about to ask that.

Comment: I understand the question, I just think my approach is wrong

Comment: How about the approach I proposed in my comment?

Comment: Well I am adding 324 to the result aren't I?

Comment: Really unclear what you're trying to do. Do you expect 324 * 24 to yield 7776? In that case, the one-liner in my original comment is a complete solution to the problem. Probably want to change the result type to `long` if x and y are of type `int` though.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear though, I'm trying to multiply two numbers, 324 and 24 via repeated addition whereby each digit is stored in an array. Yes I could just use long and forget using the array - but that's not the point. It's to use arrayLists.

Comment: hy are you using array? what is the need for splitting the numbers. Check this link here. 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_and_repeated_addition

Comment: Try doing repeated addition when the number has more than 32 digits, you can't use long. The whole idea behind this task is to simulate what the Big int class achieves.

Comment: I haven't tried that using BigInt, but the logic remains the same.

Comment: Like I said earlier, I understand the logic  behind the question however achieving this through arrayLists Is what I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier, if you use other variable names to help you along:

```
BigInt input1 = new BigInt();
BigInt multiplier = new BigInt();

BigInt nextResult = new BigInt();
BigInt lastResult = null;

while ( ... notdone ... ) {
    nextResult.digitList.clear();
    if (lastResult==null) {
        lastResult = input1;
    } else {
        ... the addition logic: nextResult = lastResult + input1 ...
    }
    ... the logic to remember that one addition step was done ...

    lastResult = nextResult;
    nextResult = new BigInt();
}
```

`lastResult` is always your result from the previous iteration. You must be careful, that you never change digits in `lastResult`. The only change to `lastResult` must be, when you assign it from `input1` or `nextResult`.

When you start with the addition, your `lastResult` has no data, because there was no "last iteration". In that case you can just initialize `lastResult` with `input1`.

`nextResult` is where you work in an addition iteration and store the new digits to. When that iteration is done, make it the `lastResult` and prepare a new `nextResult` on which to work. (In your code you sometimes use `temp` and sometimes `result` which adds confusion for you.)

The interesting part is, remembering how far you have calculated already. For instance with "5 x 3" after the first iteration you get a result and the "3" becomes "2" as there are two iterations left. Or with "123 x 15" the "15" decreases with each iteration first to "14", then "13", ... "10", "9", ... a.s.o.

This relates to the "... not done ..." part of the while condition.

There are a couple of optimizations possible here, of which I wouldn't want to tell much, because that is certainly part of your homework. Probably you should just go ahead and build some code until it works. Along the way you may already have ideas how to make things easier. It may also help, if you try to do the addition steps on paper. You may notice which parts could be done more easily. (If you don't find optimizations, don't worry - this needs practice and sometimes the brain is in such mood and sometimes not. Also your results must be correct, they should not be "cleverly optimized" and then be sometimes wrong.)

**UPDATE: on variables and object instances**

You need to make a difference between variables and the objects to which they refer.

```
nextResult = new BigInt();
```

This statement means two things: 1) You create an instance of `BigInt()` and 2) You reference that BigInt with `lastResult`.

Now this statement:

```
lastResult = nextResult;
```

THere is still the same `BigInt`, but now both `lastResult` and `nextResult` refer to that very same `BigInt`. If you change a digit in `lastResult` you actually change a digit in the `BigInt` instance. And since `nextResult` and `lastResult` refer to the same `BigInt`, both will deliver the identical values when fetching the digits.

This also means, that you do not need to copy the digits. They are already there.

Now this statement creates a new instance of `BigInt`:

```
nextResult = new BigInt();
```

Now after these three statements, `nextResult` refers to a new `BigInt` instance which is now different from the `BigInt` which is in `lastResult`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say nextResult =  new BigInt? I don't think I'm supposed to create a new object

Comment: Why do you think that you should not create a new object? If such a thing is not mentioned in the task, you should be allowed to create new objects. Let me know, if you really are not allowed to create new objects, and I will give a hint in the answer.

Comment: Right I see what you mean. For the last part, where you assign the arrayList nextResult to Last result, How do I copy the array over? I've tried using

`lastResult.digitList.clear()
lastResult.digitList.addAll(nextResult)
`

But the arrayList  lastResult becomes empty once I've run this through and I can't add anything to it

Comment: I'm updating my answer to give details about variables and instances.

Comment: Tracing through the program and itworks fine, however.. Due to the way this template was written (given a template to fill out) digitList is a Private list holds the number value (324), whereas multipliers and other numbers are stored by using a BigInt object (in this case otherBigInt holds the 24). Now the part that doesn't work (probably due to my inexperience) is the if statement, I can only equate `lastResult.digitList = digitList` This won't work and gives me a null pointer exception. Theres no input1 object Just the digitList.
`// product of calling (this) big int and other big int.`

Comment: Hmmm. I think I need some more information. How do you get your input values? Do you get them as an `ArrayList` or as a `BigInt` ? In your homework do you need to use an existing project/existing sources and add your code to a specific function or class?

Comment: It looks to me u may get an Index out of bounds exception since you clear digits....did u try re-intialising the variable?